# Load image from file and showing it in UIImageView, not working after Xcode 5/IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

So i just upgraded to Xcode 5, and set the deployment target to 7.0. And although my app looks amazing, i got this small problem.

In init in my ScreenshotViewController i do this:

```
pics = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
```

dataFilePath method beeing:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screenshots.archive"];
}
```

In my UITableViewController subclass i init a ScreenshotViewController(which basically just shows an image on a UIImageView), and set its image.

```
ScreenshotViewController *ssv = [[ScreenshotViewController alloc]init];

[[self navigationController]pushViewController:ssv animated:YES];
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageWithData:[pics objectAtIndex:row]];

[ssv.image setImage:pic];
```

This worked perfect before the updates, but now the UIImageView receives no image. 
Im checking this by noting that an image is no longer copied to my photo albums when executing this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image.image, nil, nil, nil);
```

So any suggestions what might have happened?

Comment: maybe a dumb idea, but can you see what [NSFileManager defaultManager] says when you ask fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath] ?

Comment: Did you do any debugging to verify your assumptions?

Comment: Tried, returns yes. I guess the tableview would be empty if it returned no. But thanks anyway

Comment: Okay, so i tested the pictures, by adding a UIImageView as a subview to the current view when clicking a cell. And it shows it fine.. So i guess its something with the way i set the image in the other viewcontroller.. keeping this open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating the UIImageView programmatically. Apparently something is wrong with UIImageView's since ios 7